# C++: Where is a good place for sample C++ codes to be used by a teacher?

Tags: c++, sample

I am a teacher of programming. For the C++ course, I need a good reference to provide educational example problems and their solutions. I know some popular problems but I like to see them all in a one place and choose between them.

Do you know some website to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using [a good introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)? If so, it should have lots of code samples. Otherwise, can't you write your own?

Comment: I really liked `Accelerated C++` that was written initially as part of a course. It has many examples of text processing, which might seem a little odd now that almost nobody uses the terminal anymore...

Comment: These a copyrighted materials.  You'd better check what kind of fair use clause exists in your country of residence.  Schools often have rules too.  Reference: http://home.earthlink.net/~cnew/research.htm

Comment: @James: Sounds like a high school "CS" class.  If that is the case, the teachers often don't know much more than the students.

Comment: @David: I use the terminal as much as I can.

Comment: @EdS:  Oh.  That could be.  I jumped to the conclusion that it was a college-level CS course.  I don't know how one can really teach something without being familiar with it :(.

Comment: Well... they can't, but they try :)

Comment: A teacher looking for a source to plagerize from? No wonder I have had to extensively retain every programmer fresh out of college I've ever hired.

Comment: @David: That's indeed a great book for teaching. I have taught C++ based on that book's approach for many years, and I believe successfully. (Be warned, though, if you read this and consider buying it in order to _learn_ C++ on your own. It has a _very_ steep learning curve. If you're fine with that, that's Ok, but if not, consider buying [another book instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).)

Comment: @takpar also check out this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") on stack-exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Accelerated C++ is your best bet.

editorializing note: I've gone through an enormous amount of intro C++ books. There is *so much* drek out there, it's mind-blowing. I think Accelerated C++ is pretty concise and lucid. 
It has the disadvantage of being short, so it *can't* be used as monitor-lifting fodder.

I didn't know about it at the time and I went through piles of other books. Jesse Liberty's *C++ in 24 hours* was the most useful of the books I found when I was learning. Looking back on it, that's sort of surprising, given the X in Y hours reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep the line of a book, it's a great idea since, you all the examples will have the same line of, let's say logic. A great book, that help me out was written by [H. M. Deitel](http://www.deitel.com), it has several programming books, and in my point o view, are very well explained.

Comment: Ugh, I do not like Deitel at all. They used it in my undergrad classes... not very helpful.

Comment: @Paul It's only a suggestion, it worked for my

Comment: but it’s a bad suggestion: the Deitel is generally acknowledged to be a very bad C++ book with lots of factual errors in it.

Comment: You think so, mmm... maybe that would explain a lot of things

Answer (score 0):

You can't find better questions/examples targeted on understanding of C++ (including advanced) topics than Herb Sutter's Guru of the Week series (http://gotw.ca/publications/index.htm)